# winform mschart Column chart not centering column on datapoint

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, mschart

Hello I am having a hard time understanding how to get my column chart to be centered over the X-Axis label.  IN the chart pic below you will see that I have columns based on 1/2 increments.  For my positive series the data starts on the left and ends at the x-axis label.  On my negative series the data starts at the x-axis label and continues to the right.  How do I get these columns centered over the x-axis label.  I don't understand why one series is displayed one way and the other series is displayed a different way.

Screen shot here: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/agajj.png

Code is below

```
        chartAreaDistributionHalfHour.Name = "ChartAreaDistributionHalfHour";
        chartAreaDistributionHalfHour.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
        chartAreaDistributionHalfHour.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
        chartAreaDistributionHalfHour.AxisX.IntervalAutoMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.IntervalAutoMode.VariableCount;
        chartAreaDistributionHalfHour.AxisY.IntervalAutoMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.IntervalAutoMode.VariableCount;
        chartAreaDistributionHalfHour.AxisX.LabelAutoFitMaxFontSize = 7;
        chartAreaDistributionHalfHour.AxisY.LabelAutoFitMaxFontSize = 7;
        chartAreaDistributionHalfHour.AxisX.Title = "Distribution (Half-Hourly)";
        chartAreaDistributionHalfHour.AxisY.Title = "Profit/Loss ($)";
        chartAreaDistributionHalfHour.AxisY.IsMarginVisible = false;

        seriesDistributionHalfHour.ChartArea = "ChartAreaDistributionHalfHour";
        seriesDistributionHalfHour.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column;
        seriesDistributionHalfHour.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        seriesDistributionHalfHour.Enabled = true;
        seriesDistributionHalfHour.Name = "distributionHalfHour";
        seriesDistributionHalfHourNegative.ChartArea = "ChartAreaDistributionHalfHour";
        seriesDistributionHalfHourNegative.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column;
        seriesDistributionHalfHourNegative.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        seriesDistributionHalfHourNegative.Enabled = true;
        seriesDistributionHalfHourNegative.Name = "netLossDistributionHalfHour";
        seriesDistributionHalfHourZeroLine.ChartArea = "ChartAreaDistributionHalfHour";
        seriesDistributionHalfHourZeroLine.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
        seriesDistributionHalfHourZeroLine.BorderDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.Dash;
        seriesDistributionHalfHourZeroLine.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        seriesDistributionHalfHourZeroLine.Enabled = true;
        seriesDistributionHalfHourZeroLine.Name = "netDistributionHalfHourZeroLine";

        this.chartDistributionHalfHourGraph.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(17, 49);
        this.chartDistributionHalfHourGraph.Name = "chartDistributionHalfHourGraph";
        this.chartDistributionHalfHourGraph.BorderlineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.chartDistributionHalfHourGraph.BorderlineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.Solid;
        this.chartDistributionHalfHourGraph.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Cross;
        this.chartDistributionHalfHourGraph.Visible = false;
        this.chartDistributionHalfHourGraph.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1443, 694);
        this.chartDistributionHalfHourGraph.TabIndex = 7;
        this.chartDistributionHalfHourGraph.Text = "chart2";
        this.chartDistributionHalfHourGraph.ChartAreas.Add(chartAreaDistributionHalfHour);
        this.chartDistributionHalfHourGraph.Series.Add(seriesDistributionHalfHour);
        this.chartDistributionHalfHourGraph.Series.Add(seriesDistributionHalfHourNegative);
        this.chartDistributionHalfHourGraph.Series.Add(seriesDistributionHalfHourZeroLine);
```

Comment: It's because you have two different data series for your data points. It attempts to center the two data points (one from each series) around the label which puts one series to the left of the label and one series to the right.

Comment: @Anthony Is there a way to change that behavior.  The only reason I went with 2 series is because I wanted to color code based on >0 or < 0.  Is there a way to use one series but color code based on this?

Comment: Should be able to set the color of each data point I believe. I haven't messed much with the MSChart stuff, but I believe you could. I'll try to look next time I'm at my desktop.

Comment: My stupidity, you just need to use chart type stackedcolumn.  I was using plain column.